# ¿Cómo mandar un archivo de manera asincrona?

Tags: java, gradle, servicio, descarga, clob

Tengo un servicio en Java (1.7 Gradle) donde de respuesta es un archivo

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
public byte[] send (@FormParam("test") String test) {
    byte[] res;

    OfflineDao dao = new OfflineDao();

    res = dao.getVersionAct("0", "Tipo");

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Archivo.zip");
    response.addHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(res.length));

    return res;
}
```

En el metodo de mi DAO obtengo el CLOB de la base de datos, y lo parseo con IOUtils.toByteArray

```
archivo = IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getCharacterStream(), "UTF-8");
```

El servicio funciona sin problemas, pero hay un detalle, la descarga inicia cuando termina la linea del parseo con el IOUtils, y cuando este acaba, tira el archivo completo (algo parecido a lo que hace MEGA con sus descargas, todo el "Buffer" es vía web y al final descargas lo predescargado desde el navegador)

Mi duda es, Hay alguna manera de que el archivo se vaya descargando mientras parsea? o hay alguna otra manera de realizar ésto?

PD: No puedo cambiar el tipo de dato de la base (CLOB)

Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando java 8 o java 7 podrías ocupar Streaming. De esta forma puedes liberar contenido apenas lo estés leyendo.

```
StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, 
                                            WebApplicationException {
            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

            // Aquí escribes mediante el writer lo que vas leyendo desde tu CLOB
            copy(clob.getBinaryStream(1), os);
            writer.flush();
        }
};

return Response.ok(stream).build();
```

Una breve reseña que te puede ayudar es https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response